# Maithri Bodhisatvas Ata pirikara

Tags: brahma, maitreya-buddha

I recently got to know that the Ata Pirikara that is to be given to Maithree Bodhisatva at the time of the renunciation by the Maha Brahma has already been created and ready.

Is there anything related to this sort of dharma in the tripitaka?

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of a ‘Atapirikara’ from Maha Brahma, but the legend says: “When Maitreya Buddha appears in the world, he will come to Kukkuta-padagiri (the Cook's-foot Mountain) – presently known as ‘Gurpa’, awaken Maha Kassapa, receive the Buddha’s robes from him, and then begin to announce the new dispensation.
[Maha Kassapa](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/hecker/wheel345.html) had been praised by the Buddha as being equal to him in many respects. He had been the only monk with whom the Buddha had exchanged robes.

> Then both Master and disciple walked towards Rajagaha. On the way, the Buddha wanted to rest and went off the road to the root of a tree. Maha Kassapa then folded his double-robe fourfold and requested the Master to sit on it as this would bring him, Kassapa, much benefit for a long time. The Buddha sat down on Kassapa's robe and said: "Soft is your robe of patched cloth, Kassapa." Hearing this, Kassapa replied: "May the Blessed One, O Lord, accept this robe of patched cloth out of compassion for me!" — "But, Kassapa, can you wear these hempen, worn-out rag-robes of mine?" Full of joy, Kassapa said: "Certainly, Lord, I can wear the Blessed One's rough and worn-out rag-robes."
>
> This exchange of robes can be regarded as a great distinction bestowed on Kassapa, an honor which was not shared by any other disciple. By that exchange of robes the Buddha may have intended to motivate Kassapa to observe some other "austere practices" (dhutanga) as for instance, wearing only the triple set of robes, going for alms and not omitting any houses on the almsround. This would be a mode of conduct in conformity with wearing the Buddha's patched rag-robes. Thus the commentator says. However, the Buddha's offer may have been a quite spontaneous act in response to his being offered Kassapa's robe.

It is this very same rough and worn-out rag-robe that the Blessed One first wore and then given to Maha Kassapa, and in turn he too wore till his Pari-Nibbhana, that Maitreya Buddha will come to accept. Some say that Maha Kassapa didn’t attain Pari-Nibbhana. Instead, he took Samadhi within the rock - that Maha Kassapa will offer the robes of the Gautama Buddha to the future Buddha when Maitryea Buddha descends to this realm in order to share the next basket of teachings with the world. Others say it is an “Adhisthana” (by the power of his will to make such an event happen) that he made at the time he attained Pari-Nibbhana.

Comment: Can even an Arahant stay in samadhi for such a long time?

Comment: No.. Only those who are ignorant of the Dhamma would say such. Arahant Kassapa attained Pari-Nibbhana over 2500 years ago. The type of Samadhi that you are referring to is called nirodha-samāpatti. 'attainment of extinction'. The maximum time that as Arahant can stay in this Samadhi is seven days.

Answer (score 0):

*Ata Pirikara that is to be given to Maithree Bodhisatva at the time of the renunciation by the Maha Brahma has already been created and ready.*

I haven't heard of that specific info until now.

But here is more general information regarding this.

- There's one last Dharma Desana after another 2500 years (at 5000 after physical deth of Gauthama Buddha.)
- In the future, human age goes down to 10 years.(this takes like 100000++ years /there's no exact number I remember).
- Then comes grate destruction of human civilization.(only little amount of humans left after this).
- Then human age grow again. Like 10 to 20,40,100,1000, upto "number I don't like to post(has reasons). This take like millions of years. Then this number start to drop again. When this number reach 80,000 ; That's when Maithree Bodhisatva come to Earth to become Buddha.
- On Earth that's long long time, that people can't even grasp it. But there are planes of existence which has long and long living age (like millions of years). **So those beings see the whole process and it's like next year for them. So it's normal for them to be ready for next event.** **That's the reason for given statement in the question.**

**Guide :-**

- age doesn't jump from 10 to 20,100 to 1000. It's a continuous process. Gradually increasing or decreasing.
- at the great distraction, people kill each other.
- It's not like people at 100,000 years age live 100,000 years like people(now people) imagine, they(people at 100,000) feel it same as us feel 100 years.
  You can grasp this idea using below example.

Ex- Compare how much time a normal person live (in this time) to the life of a bee.
workers live on average 15–38 days in the summer and 150–200 days in the winter.
So take 100 days as their age.
And take 100 years as human age.
What can us humans do in 100 days. We are just babies at 100 days. But bees do all of life processes in that 100 days.

[More info(some numbers in Buddhism)](https://comeandseethebuddhism.blogspot.com/2018/09/measurements-in-buddhism.html?m=1)

If anyone is interested, I can put more info here.
Thanks . ☸️.

Comment: Some may say above statements are not valid, not reasonable, not possible, there are no evidence for this kind of situations; that's the meaning of unimaginable, that's a result of low age level of a human life. (compared to)